# How to populate checkboxes using JavaScript in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input, laravel-5, dynamically-generated

I want to populate a list of check boxes dynamically using JavaScript. I have done the following:

In my `balde view`:

```
<div  id="demo" class="collapse" > 
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
          <div class="panel-body" id="demos" style="max-height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll;" >

             <input type="checkbox" name="specific[]" value=" "> <br>

           </div>    
     </div>
 </div>
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#ItemID').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var itemID= e.target.value;


        $.getJSON('/xxxxx/list?itemID=' + itemID, function(data){
           $('#demos').empty();
           $.each(data,function(index, subcatlist){
               $('#demos').append('<input value="'+subcatlist[0].ID+'">'+subcatlist[0].Name+'</input>');
            });
          });             
        });
      });
```

`route.php` passes wanted data.

I want my view to be like this, a checkbox followed by Names:

[image: Expected result]

But what I'm getting is this:

[image: Actual result]

I am getting Names to the view, but the leading check box is missing and replaced with a textbox. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: in you append call you are not giving `type="checkbox"`. Can you please try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#demos').append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + subcatlist[0].ID + '"/>' + subcatlist[0].Name);
```

I think this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things which are wrong.

1. as I have mentioned in the comment, you have missed `type="checkbox"`.
2. `subcatlist` should be `data` and instead of using using 0 , use index.

so your code should be like below.

```
$.each(data, function (index, subcatlist) {
        $('#demos').append('<input value="' + data[index].ID + '" type="checkbox">' + data[index].Name + '</input>');
    });
```